# Запись цифр числа в массив

Tags: java, массивы

Задание: записать число N в массив наоборот.
Например:

```
N = 348597
```

А массив должен иметь вид:

```
[7,9,5,8,4,3]
```

Реализация вывода числа наоборот понятна, но как разбить число `int`, не знаю.

Comment: Ну собственно и наоборот неправильно поняли)

Comment: Что-то я не вижу единицы, двойки и шестерки, которые должны получиться при `10 - N[i]`. Не говоря уже от том, как это все разломается, когда среди цифр исходного числа будет `0`.

Comment: Создать массив и добавлять туда по числу.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод [`IntStream.iterate​(seed,hasNext,next)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-):

```java
int n = 348597;
int[] arr = IntStream
        // начинаем с 'n', каждое последующее число -
        // это текущее число, делённое на 10
        // получаем [348597, 34859, 3485, 348, 34, 3]
        .iterate(n, i -> i / 10 > 0 || i % 10 > 0, i -> i / 10)
        // получаем последнюю цифру
        .map(i -> i % 10)
        // собираем в массив
        .toArray();

// выводим массив
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [7, 9, 5, 8, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[6];
    int number = 348597;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        arr[i] += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }

    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println(arr[0]);
    System.out.println(arr[5]);
}
```

Comment: зачем вы привязываетесь в цикле к константе "6"? попахивает жестким кодированием...

Comment: Можно было бы получать значения с клавиатуры, написать класс и функции, но зачем? Это скорее всего учебная задача. Пусть допишет arr.length или передает аргументом количество.

Comment: нет, не в этом дело. у вас должен быть метод, который в параметрах принимает число , а возвращает массив его чисел с реверсом.

Comment: Вы сейчас серьезно? Человек не способен создать функцию и вернуть массив? Уже все готово, осталось подставить нужное число в number через агрумент функции и вернуть массив....

Comment: хорошо, подставьте в свой код другое число. например 123456789

Answer (score 0):

Это легко решается рекурсией:

```
public static int[] getRevertedDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative numbers not supported");
    }
    return getRevertedDigits(n, 1);
}

private static int[] getRevertedDigits(int n, int size) {
    int[] res;
    int d = n / 10;
    if (d > 0) {
        res = getRevertedDigits(d, size + 1);
    } else {
        res = new int[size];
    }
    res[size - 1] = n % 10;
    return res;
}
```